# JavaScript Not Executing on Initial Template Rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, haml

I'm experiencing a problem where JavaScript isn't functioning as expected during the initial rendering of my web template (haml). Although I've included JavaScript code, it doesn't run on the initial page load. Interestingly, even a basic `console.log` statement doesn't appear in the console until I refresh the page.

this is what my template looks like

```
- if user.present?
  %div#button-container
    %a#my-test.button{'data-user-id' => user.id, :href => '#'}
      = image_tag('https://test.button.svg', id: 'Button', style: 'padding-top: 20px;')

:javascript
  console.log('Inside Javascript')
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('Inside document.ready()')
  });
```

I'm finding it difficult to understand what the issue could be here. Neither console logs anything during the initial template rendering, but upon reloading the page, they log messages, indicating that the JavaScript is now functioning correctly.

Comment: Can you share a live example in codepen or codesandbox?

Comment: Sure, here it is: https://codepen.io/Muhammad-Ushay/pen/oNJqVJd?editors=1111

Comment: This seems to work:
https://codepen.io/yonatankra/pen/QWzmXEP?editors=1111

Comment: Yeah, Its supposed to work, but it does not in my code. Thats basically the question.

Comment: The idea of creating a live example is to duplicate the issue. Can you reproduce the issue in codepen? Maybe you have some special configuration in your local dev environment?

Comment: Yeah, I cant reproduce it here, I agree that it seems to be some issue with my local environment.